# Minishift start error Checking for setuid bit ... FAIL on macOS Ventura version 13.1

Tags: virtual-environment, macos-ventura, minishift

I want to start minishift on my macOS Ventura Version 13.1 I set up virtual environment following this [link](https://docs.okd.io/3.11/minishift/getting-started/setting-up-virtualization-environment.html)

However, when I try minishift start command following lines are printed:

```
-- Starting profile 'minishift'

-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK

-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK

-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is valid ... OK

-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is supported ... OK

-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'hyperkit' is supported on this platform ... OK

-- Checking if hyperkit is installed ... 

Hyperkit is available at /usr/local/bin/hyperkit

Checking for setuid bit ... FAIL

See the 'Setting Up the Virtualization Environment' topic 
(https://docs.okd.io/latest/minishift/getting-started/setting-up-virtualization- 
environment.html) for more information.
```

I could not find any solution about this specific failure. Thanks for any help.